# Return quoted data from SQL query result only if needed

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have simple SQL:

```
select product.name from products;
```

In my table I have 2 products: wheel, steering wheel.

So my result is:

```
wheel
steering wheel
```

How to get quoted result if the result has more than 1 word ?:

```
wheel
"steering wheel"
```

I tried to use `quote_literal` function but the result is unfortunately always quoted.
`quote_literal` works like I need only for constant strings like: `quoted_literal('steering wheel')` / `quoted_literal('wheel')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (product.name LIKE '% %')
THEN quoted_ident(product.name) ELSE product.name END
FROM products;
```

Comment: This solution is faster because you do only one SELECT and don't merge results.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE position(' ' in name)= 0
union
SELECT '"'|| name ||'"' FROM products WHERE position(' ' in name)<>0
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a3dd/18)

Comment: At least use a `union all` to avoid the step of removing duplicates - but Tom is right: a `case` will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  product.NAME,array_length(string_to_array(product.NAME,' '),1) words_cnt -- will return number of words in product.name
from product
```

and use the following  *select* to get your desired output

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN array_length(string_to_array(product.NAME, ' '), 1) > 1
            THEN format('''%s''', product.NAME)
        ELSE product.NAME
        END
FROM product
```

Comment: `name LIKE '% %'` will be *much*  more efficient that converting the string to an array just to check if that array has more than one element

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, you're right!!,I posted it to show an another approach